# How do I change mix up tables to Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to use Sequelize to mix up tables, but I couldn't find out how to.

```sql
SELECT count(*) as counts
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM board order by id desc limit 10) as board
WHERE board.login_id = 1234
```

How do I represent this in Sequelize

Comment: Could you please also add the sequelize models created for `counts` and `board`? Also, please update the question with some code that you might have tried until now to get results?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this in sequelize .

```
//board means your model name

let result = await board.count({
    order: [sequelize.literal('id DESC')],
    limit: 10,
    where: { login_id: 1234 },
    as: 'board'
})
```

Comment: FROM
  (SELECT * FROM board order by id desc limit 10) as board

Comment: request                        
SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM `board` AS `board` WHERE `board`.`login_id` = 1234;